# Finding the dual of the feasible set of a linear matrix inequality (LMI)

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality, spectrahedra

I am stuck at problem 3 of [this homework assignment](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-972-algebraic-techniques-and-semidefinite-optimization-spring-2006/assignments/hw1.pdf) about semidefinite programming and linear matrix inequalities (LMIs).

> Given a set $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that strictly contains the origin, we define the dual set $\mathcal{S}^o$ as
>   $$
> \mathcal{S}^o:=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n: y^Tx\leq1, \forall x \in \mathcal{S}\}
> $$
>   Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the feasible set of an SDP i.e.
>   $$
> \mathcal{S}:= \left \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^kx_iA_i \preceq A_0 \right \}
> $$
>   where $A_0 \succeq 0$ and the $A_i$ are symmetric matrices. Here $X\succeq Y$ means that $\langle (X-Y)u,u\rangle\ge 0$ for all $u\in\Bbb R^n$.
>
> Find a convenient description of $S^o$. Can you optimize a linear function over $S^o$?

I have tried the simple case where the set $\mathcal{S}$ is a bounded polytope, in this case the dual set is the dual polytope which can be characterized as the vectors $\{y: y^Tv_i \leq 1\, \forall i=1, \ldots, k \}$ where $v_i$ are the vertices of the polytope. In this case maximizing a linear function over the dual polytope $c^Ty$ yields $||c||$ the norm associated to the original polytope. But I have no idea what happens in the case of general linear matrix inequalities.

Comment: What are the $A_i$?

Comment: Symmetric matrices of the same dimension

Comment: For $x\in\Bbb R^n$ let $H_x := \{y : y^Tx\le 1\}$ and define the map $\phi : \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^k$ by $\phi(y) := (y^TA_1y,\ldots,y^TA_ky)^T$. Moreover, let $B_0 := \{y : y^TA_0y = 1\}$. Then $S = \{x : \phi(B_0)\subset H_x\}$ and $S^\circ = \bigcap_{x\in S}H_x$. Hence, we trivially have $\phi(B_0)\subset S^\circ$. I guess that also the opposite inclusion holds, but I cannot show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition
$$y^Tx\leq1 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^kx_iA_i \preceq A_0 $$
is equivalent with
$$\max_{x  \in \mathbb{R}^n} \{ y^Tx : \sum_{i=1}^kx_iA_i \preceq A_0 \} \leq 1 $$
If you now apply SDP duality, you get a "$\min_y$" on the left hand side. You can then proceed to replace the min operator with "$\exists y$".

Comment: Thank you very much! This leads to the answer.